# Why this yacc file doesn't compile

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I am new to yacc/lex, I was trying to compile my first program file.y.

```
%{
   #include <ctype.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #define YYSTYPE double /* double type for yacc stack */  
%}

%%
Lines   :       Lines S '\n' { printf("OK \n"); }
        |       S '\n’
        |       error '\n' {yyerror("Error: reenter last line:");
                                yyerrok; };
S       :  '(' S ')’
        |  '[' S ']’
        |   /* empty */    ;
%%

#include "lex.yy.c"

void yyerror(char * s)
/* yacc error handler */
{
 fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void)
{
 return yyparse();
}
```

and, file.l

```
%{
%}

%%
[ \t]     { /* skip blanks and tabs */ }
\n|.      { return yytext[0]; }
%%
```

I have compiled lex file (file.l) with

```
lex file.l
```

afterwards, yacc file (file.y) with

```
yacc file.y
```

and Error messenger:

```
"file.y", line 9: multicharacter literal tokens not supported
file.y:9 parser name defined to default :"parse"
symbol S used, not defined as token, and no rules for it
2 rules never reduced
file.y contains 2 useless nonterminals and 2 useless rules.
"file.y", line 9: Start symbol Lines does not derive any sentence.
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can You help me out?

Comment: I think you are using `bison++`, which is not bison. Don't do that if you want to follow tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at line 9:

```
        |       S '\n’
```

Should be

```
        |       S '\n'
```

Note the change from a random unicode character that looks like a fancy angled single quote to a standard single quote character.

You also have the same mistake on lines 12 and 13.

Comment: Not a backquote, but rather UTF-8 E2 80 99, Unicode U+2019, or RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK ([link](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)).

Comment: Thank You, @Bill Lynch.